# Kafka Consumer/Producer test in Spring Kafka

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-test, spring-kafka

I am currently working on Kafka module where I am using `spring-kafka` abstraction of Kafka communication. I am able to integrate the producer & consumer from real implementation standpoint however, I am not sure how to test (specifically integration test) the business logic surrounds at consumer with `@KafkaListener`. I tried to follow `spring-kafk` documentation and various blogs on the topic but none of those answer my intended question.

**Spring Boot test class**

```
//imports not mentioned due to brevity

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = PaymentAccountUpdaterApplication.class,
                webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
public class CardUpdaterMessagingIntegrationTest {

    private final static String cardUpdateTopic = "TP.PRF.CARDEVENTS";

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @ClassRule
    public static KafkaEmbedded kafkaEmbedded =
            new KafkaEmbedded(1, false, cardUpdateTopic);

    @Test
    public void sampleTest() throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> consumerConfig =
                KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps("test", "false", kafkaEmbedded);
        consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);

        ConsumerFactory<String, String> cf = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfig);
        ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(cardUpdateTopic);
        containerProperties.setMessageListener(new SafeStringJsonMessageConverter());
        KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String>
                container = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(cf, containerProperties);

        BlockingQueue<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> records = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        container.setupMessageListener((MessageListener<String, String>) data -> {
            System.out.println("Added to Queue: "+ data);
            records.add(data);
        });
        container.setBeanName("templateTests");
        container.start();
        ContainerTestUtils.waitForAssignment(container, kafkaEmbedded.getPartitionsPerTopic());


        Map<String, Object> producerConfig = KafkaTestUtils.senderProps(kafkaEmbedded.getBrokersAsString());
        producerConfig.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        producerConfig.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

        ProducerFactory<String, Object> pf =
                new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfig);
        KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(pf);

        String payload = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(accountWrapper());
        kafkaTemplate.send(cardUpdateTopic, 0, payload);
        ConsumerRecord<String, String> received = records.poll(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        assertThat(received).has(partition(0));
    }


    @After
    public void after() {
        kafkaEmbedded.after();
    }

    private AccountWrapper accountWrapper() {
        return AccountWrapper.builder()
                .eventSource("PROFILE")
                .eventName("INITIAL_LOAD_CARD")
                .eventTime(LocalDateTime.now().toString())
                .eventID("8730c547-02bd-45c0-857b-d90f859e886c")
                .details(AccountDetail.builder()
                        .customerId("idArZ_K2IgE86DcPhv-uZw")
                        .vaultId("912A60928AD04F69F3877D5B422327EE")
                        .expiryDate("122019")
                        .build())
                .build();
    }
}
```

**Listener Class**

```
@Service
public class ConsumerMessageListener {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConsumerMessageListener.class);

    private ConsumerMessageProcessorService consumerMessageProcessorService;

    public ConsumerMessageListener(ConsumerMessageProcessorService consumerMessageProcessorService) {
        this.consumerMessageProcessorService = consumerMessageProcessorService;
    }


    @KafkaListener(id = "cardUpdateEventListener",
            topics = "${kafka.consumer.cardupdates.topic}",
            containerFactory = "kafkaJsonListenerContainerFactory")
    public void processIncomingMessage(Payload<AccountWrapper,Object> payloadContainer,
                                       Acknowledgment acknowledgment,
                                       @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
                                       @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) String partitionId,
                                       @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) String offset) {

        try {
            // business logic to process the message
            consumerMessageProcessorService.processIncomingMessage(payloadContainer);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Unhandled exception in card event message consumer. Discarding offset commit." +
                    "message:: {}, details:: {}", e.getMessage(), messageMetadataInfo);
            throw e;
        }
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    }
}
```

My question is: In the test class I am asserting the partition, payload etc which is polling from `BlockingQueue`, however, my question is how can I verify that my business logic in the class annotated with `@KafkaListener` is getting executed properly and routing the messages to different topic based on error handling and other business scenarios. In some of the examples, I saw `CountDownLatch` to assert which I don't want to put in my business logic to assert in a production grade code. Also the message processor is `Async` so, how to assert the execution, not sure.

Any help, appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is getting executed properly and routing the messages to different topic based on error handling and other business scenarios.

An integration test can consume from that "different" topic to assert that the listener processed it as expected.

You could also add a `BeanPostProcessor` to your test case and wrap the `ConsumerMessageListener` bean in a proxy to verify the input arguments are as expected.

**EDIT**

Here is an example of wrapping the listener in a proxy...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So53678801Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So53678801Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter converter() {
        return new StringJsonMessageConverter();
    }

    public static class Foo {

        private String bar;

        public Foo() {
            super();
        }

        public Foo(String bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        public String getBar() {
            return this.bar;
        }

        public void setBar(String bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Foo [bar=" + this.bar + "]";
        }

    }

}

@Component
class Listener {

    @KafkaListener(id = "so53678801", topics = "so53678801")
    public void processIncomingMessage(Foo payload,
            Acknowledgment acknowledgment,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) String partitionId,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) String offset) {

        System.out.println(payload);
        // ...
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    }

}
```

and

```
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=manual
```

and

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { So53678801Application.class,
        So53678801ApplicationTests.TestConfig.class})
public class So53678801ApplicationTests {

    @ClassRule
    public static EmbeddedKafkaRule embededKafka = new EmbeddedKafkaRule(1, false, "so53678801");

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        System.setProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers",
                embededKafka.getEmbeddedKafka().getBrokersAsString());
    }

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

    @Autowired
    private ListenerWrapper wrapper;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        this.template.send("so53678801", "{\"bar\":\"baz\"}");
        assertThat(this.wrapper.latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isTrue();
        assertThat(this.wrapper.argsReceived[0]).isInstanceOf(Foo.class);
        assertThat(((Foo) this.wrapper.argsReceived[0]).getBar()).isEqualTo("baz");
        assertThat(this.wrapper.ackCalled).isTrue();
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class TestConfig {

        @Bean
        public static ListenerWrapper bpp() { // BPPs have to be static
            return new ListenerWrapper();
        }

    }

    public static class ListenerWrapper implements BeanPostProcessor, Ordered {

        private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        private Object[] argsReceived;

        private boolean ackCalled;

        @Override
        public int getOrder() {
            return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
        }

        @Override
        public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            if (bean instanceof Listener) {
                ProxyFactory pf = new ProxyFactory(bean);
                pf.setProxyTargetClass(true); // unless the listener is on an interface
                pf.addAdvice(interceptor());
                return pf.getProxy();
            }
            return bean;
        }

        private MethodInterceptor interceptor() {
            return invocation -> {
                if (invocation.getMethod().getName().equals("processIncomingMessage")) {
                    Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                    this.argsReceived = Arrays.copyOf(args, args.length);
                    Acknowledgment ack = (Acknowledgment) args[1];
                    args[1] = (Acknowledgment) () -> {
                        this.ackCalled = true;
                        ack.acknowledge();
                    };
                    try {
                        return invocation.proceed();
                    }
                    finally {
                        this.latch.countDown();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    return invocation.proceed();
                }
            };
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Gary. I added my error topic to Embedded Kafka to initialize and listener to invoked when send similar to event topic. This works fine. The received object is a Json which I am planning parse and assert on various properties which was sent by business methods based on my scenarios. I couldn't understand though, the input argument verification via ConsumerMessageListener, could you please elaborate a bit.

Comment: See the edit to my answer for an example of how to wrap the listener.