# How to unit test a Kafka listener that doesn't change any internal variables

Tags: testing, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-test

I've written a Kafka listener in Spring, takes in a message, does some transforming, saves it to a database. Hardly novel stuff.

I'm looking to test the functionality of the message hitting the kafka topic and being ingested by my application (basically just testing if my topic configured right, right group etc).

I have initially achieved this by including an arbitrary payload variable into the class, setting this variable, and checking it's value when I send the right data to embedded kafka. This has worked fine. However, it feels like bad engineering to me to have this variable exist solely for my testing purposes. Is there a way of testing this small bit, the ingest, without this arbitrary variable? I'll be doing separate database testing in the future too.

Comment: Are you able to share the code? The Spring-Kafka docs cover testing fairly well. So does the TestContainers site. Also, if using databases with Kafka, Kafka Connect would be recommended outside of Spring

Comment: There is also Spring Integration with its channel adapters for Apache Kafka, as well as JDBC. So, you can build an integration flow for your task. Spring Integration also suggest a testing framework to easy mock endpoints in the flow, so you can verify the flow by itself in the test and no effect for your production code: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#test-context

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53678801/kafka-consumer-producer-test-in-spring-kafka/53684073#53684073) for a technique to wrap the listener and capture the `ConsumerRecord`.